# Use a 2-D matrix to represent data

Tags: java

[image]
Use a 2-D matrix to represent data in the following format:

The user is required to input the sales of above mentioned cold drinks in the specified cities. Based on the data entered by the
user find out which city consumes the maximum cold drink and which cold drink is sold most.

Comment: Then go back to your course material or ask your teacher. You learn programming by doing, not by copying the work of others. When you have tried something and have a specific problem you are welcome to ask here. But in any case show what you have done.

Comment: You will find people who will solve assignments for you. But that only means that you will fail the examn. Try to do your stuff alone, read basic tutorials, and ask for something *particular* when it arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will work:

```
String arr[][]=new String[4][4];

//For reading name of Cold Drink
System.out.println("ENTER NAME OF COLD DRINKS");
for(int r=1;r<4;r++)
   arr[r][0]=sc.nextLine();

//For reading name of Cities
System.out.println("ENTER NAME OF CITIES");
for(int c=1;c<4;c++)
   arr[0][c]=sc.nextLine();

//For reading sales value
for(int r=1;r<4;r++)
{
 for(int c=1;c<4;c++)
  {
    System.out.println("ENTER SALES VALUE OF " + arr[r][0] + " IN CITY " + 
    arr[0][c]);
    arr[r][c]=sc.nextLine();
  }
}

//To display in format
for(int r=0;r<4;r++)
{
  for(int c=0;c<4;c++)
    System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
  System.out.println();
}

//Which city consumes maximum cold drink
int maxconsumption=0;
String city=" ";
for(int c=1;c<4;c++)
{
 int temp=0;
 for(int r=1;r<4;r++)
    temp+=Integer.parseInt(arr[r][c]);
 if(temp>maxconsumption)
  {
    maxconsumption=temp;
    city=arr[0][c];
  }
 }
 System.out.println("CITY " + city +" CONSUMES MAXIMUM COLD DRINK WITH 
 VALUE = " + maxconsumption);

 //Most popular brand
 int maxsales=0;
 String brand=" ";
 for(int r=1;r<4;r++)
 {
  int temp1=0;
  for(int c=1;c<4;c++)
     temp1+=Integer.parseInt(arr[r][c]);
  if(temp1>maxsales)
  {
    maxsales=temp1;
    brand=arr[r][0];
  }
 }
 System.out.println("MOST POPULAR BRAND IS " +  brand + " WITH SALES = " + 
 maxsales);
```

And if the output format requires any formatting you can do it on your own.

Comment: It's a bad practice to answer "Do my homework for me" (aka `plzsendtehcodez`) questions. No users benefit from that.

Comment: You know when I used to get get stuck I didn't have this option. So  I know the feeling...

Comment: Aside from you not doing a pupil any favor when you do his homework, why did you use a procedural approach instead of a class?

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. Really appreciate :) But it's not working

Comment: Its working now. There were minor mistyping you could have corrected it.

Comment: It's solved in the most basic way possible. So, instead of just copy paste focus on how it's working. It might help you